# Trimming all string fields coming from logstash - jdbc input

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, jdbc, db2, logstash

I am trying to trim leading and trailing whitespaces from **ALL** string fields, returned from JDBC input. The table rows contain such spaces but I don' t want to send them to mongoDB and elasticsearch, so I should somehow trim these data before sending these targets.

JDBC input plugin connects to DB2 on mainframe. I can trim string fields in select statement and can also introduce a kv filter, specifying all string fields one by one. But I need to find the most efficient alternative to achieve this.

Thank you in advance

Here is my logstash config;

```
input {
  jdbc{
    jdbc_driver_library => "<lib>"
    jdbc_driver_class => "<class>"
    jdbc_connection_string => "<conn_str>"
    jdbc_user => "<user>"
    jdbc_password => "<pass>"
    schedule => "* * * * *"
    use_column_value => true
    tracking_column => "<field1>"
    last_run_metadata_path => "<path>"
    statement => "
        SELECT *
        FROM <table>
        WHERE
        <field1> > :sql_last_value
        ORDER BY <field1> ASC
    "
  }
}

output {
  mongodb {
    uri => "mongodb://<server1>:27017"
    database => "<db>"
    collection => "<collection>"
    id => "mongo_id"
  }

  elasticsearch {
    index => "dtcomo"
    hosts => ["<server1>:9200","<server2>:9200","<server3>:9200"]
  }
}
```

Comment: Define your terms:  "more efficient".   Usually best to do bulk processing where resources are cheapest and more plentiful...

Comment: @mao By saying most efficient, I meant the ability to do it with the least effort, most robust and lowest resource intensive way. It can be a standard parameter in db2 jdbc connection string, or a logstash filter to automatically trim all strings, I don' t know...